# Does $-\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}{n}} \le \frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n} \le \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}{n}} \phantom{1},(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inequality, vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I'm trying to prove the following inequality:

$$
 -\sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}{n}} \le \frac{x_1+...+x_n}{n} \le \sqrt{\frac{x_1^2+...+x_n^2}{n}} \phantom{15},(x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}
$$

The exercise seems very simple but I have problems in solving it. I was thinking about using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $\lvert u\cdot v\rvert \le \left\lVert u\right\rVert \left\lVert v \right\rVert$ but I'm not sure if it is correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey bro, if you want further information you can read https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medias_potenciales (translate it to your language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\sqrt{n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2}=\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n1^2\sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2}\geq\sqrt{\left(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right)^2}=\left|\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\right|,$$ which gives
$$\left|\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k}{n}\right|\leq\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k^2}{n}},$$ which is your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in relation to the vectors
$$
u = (x_1/n, \cdots,x_n/n), \quad v = (1,\cdots,1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

It's an equality if
all the $x_i$
are equal and negative.